# C#, Linq2Sql: Is it possible to concatenate two queryables into one?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression-trees, iqueryable

**I have one queryable** where I have used various [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.where.aspx) and [`WhereBetween`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553443/c-linq2sql-creating-a-predicate-to-find-elements-within-a-number-of-ranges/553457#553457) statements to narrow the collection down to a certain set. Now **I need to add kind of a `Where || WhereBetween`**. In other words, I can't just chain them together like I have up till now, cause that will work as an And. So, how can I do this?

**I see two possibilities:**

1. **Create two queryables** from the one I have, one using the `Where`, and one using `WhereBetween`. **And then concatenate them**. Don't know if this is even possible? Also, although not in my particular case, you would most likely end up with duplicates...
2. Somehow **merge the `Where` expression and the expression created in the `WhereBetween`** with some sort of Or.

---

The first, as mentioned, I am not sure is even possible. And if it was, I'm not so sure it is a good way to do it.

The second, I can see as an option, but not totally sure about all the details. Below is the `WhereBetween` method from my other question, which I now use and it works great:

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereBetween<TSource, TValue>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selector,
        IEnumerable<Range<TValue>> ranges)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
        var member = Expression.Invoke(selector, param);
        Expression body = null;
        foreach (var range in ranges)
        {
            var filter = Expression.AndAlso(
                Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member,
                     Expression.Constant(range.A, typeof(TValue))),
                Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member,
                     Expression.Constant(range.B, typeof(TValue))));
            body = body == null ? filter : Expression.OrElse(body, filter);
        }
        return body == null ? source : source.Where(
            Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, param));
    }
```

I'm thinking that I could maybe extract the expression building portion of it into a new method. Perhaps like this:

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereBetween<TSource, TValue>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selector,
        IEnumerable<Range<TValue>> ranges)
    {
        return source.Where(WhereBetween(selector, ranges));
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> WhereBetween<TSource, TValue>(
        Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selector,
        IEnumerable<Range<TValue>> ranges)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
        var member = Expression.Invoke(selector, param);
        Expression body = null;
        foreach (var range in ranges)
        {
            var filter = Expression.AndAlso(
                Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member,
                     Expression.Constant(range.A, typeof(TValue))),
                Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member,
                     Expression.Constant(range.B, typeof(TValue))));
            body = body == null ? filter : Expression.OrElse(body, filter);
        }
        return body == null 
            ? ø => true
            : Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, param);
    }
```

I could then use that new method to get the expression instead of the queryable. So, lets say I have the `WhereBetween(ø => ø.Id, someRange)` and for example `ø => ø.SomeValue == null`. How can I combine those two with Or? I'm looking at the `Expression.OrElse` used in the `WhereBetween` method, and I think that might be what I need, or maybe this the `Expression.Or`. But I'm very unstable on this expression stuff, so I am not sure what to choose here, or even if I am on the right track :p

Could someone give me some pointers here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options here - `Queryable.Union`, or expression combination. I'd generally favor the latter, via `OrElse` - which (with LINQ-to-SQL at least) you can do with 2 expressions (see below) - but in either case it should get composed:

```
    using(var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        ctx.Log = Console.Out;
        Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> lhs =
            x => x.Country == "UK";
        Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> rhs =
            x => x.ContactName.StartsWith("A");

        var arr1 = ctx.Customers.Where(
            lhs.OrElse(rhs)).ToArray();

        var arr2 = ctx.Customers.Where(lhs)
            .Union(ctx.Customers.Where(rhs)).ToArray();
    }
```

Both `arr1` and `arr2` each only perform 1 database hit (although the TSQL is different; the first has an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause; the second has two separate queries with `UNION`).

Here's the extension method I used:

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrElse<T>(
    this Expression<Func<T, bool>> lhs,
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> rhs)
{
    var row = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "row");
    var body = Expression.OrElse(
        Expression.Invoke(lhs, row),
        Expression.Invoke(rhs, row));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, row);
}
```

Comment: That row thing could be anything right? (Any string that is, of course)

Comment: Thinking of sql performance and such, is it more efficient with a `UNION` or an `OR` in the `WHERE`clause?

Comment: Very nice.  This question keeps coming up (in variations) and your OrElse just might be the magic bullet that solves them all.

Comment: Yes, it could be "row", "x", or "Fred". Re performance: you'd need to profile it... different queries my behave differently. In *general* OR would be more efficient, but there are cases where UNION turns out to be better; and cases when two separate queries are better.

Comment: Nice. Expression stuff is slowly but steadily starting to make sense, hehe. Looks like it will work, although I wont get to test it out fully until Monday. Will probably stick with the OR, since that is more efficient in *general* =) Thank you, once again!