# asp.net mvc LINQ datetime problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
   string NewsFillter = string.Empty;
            List<string> PublishDatePostMeta = (from post in postrepository.GetAllPosts()
                              join pstmt in postrepository.GetAllPostMetas()
                              on post.int_PostId equals pstmt.int_PostId
                              where (post.int_PostTypeId == 4 && post.int_PostStatusId == 2 && post.int_OrganizationId == layoutrep.GetSidebarDetailById(SidebarDetailsId).int_OrganizationId) && pstmt.vcr_MetaKey=="Publish Date"
                              select pstmt.vcr_MetaValue).ToList();
            int DatesCount = PublishDatePostMeta.Count();           
            foreach (string PublishDate in PublishDatePostMeta)
            {
                if (PublishDate != "")
                {
                   NewsFillter += System.DateTime.Now + ">=" + Convert.ToDateTime(PublishDate);
                }
            }                            

            var postsidebar = from post in postrepository.GetAllPosts()
                              join pstmt in postrepository.GetAllPostMetas()
                              on post.int_PostId equals pstmt.int_PostId
                              where (post.int_PostTypeId == 4 && post.int_PostStatusId == 2 && post.int_OrganizationId == layoutrep.GetSidebarDetailById(SidebarDetailsId).int_OrganizationId)
                              && (pstmt.vcr_MetaKey.Contains(filter) && pstmt.vcr_MetaValue.Contains("true")) 
                              select post;
```

1st question .The thing is that how  **NewsFillter** would be accomdated in the postsidebar query in the pstmt object after true ( i would be putting it in contains,equals join or what) .

2nd question . is there any way that a chunk (between &&s) return enumerable and i can get away with this. at this moment it is not allowing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't udnerstood you properly, but if you want to apply multiple filters, here is my solution:

```
//Book is a table in the database
List<Expression<Func<Book, bool>>> filters = new List<Expression<Func<Book, bool>>>();
IQueryable<Book> query = dc.Books;

filters.Add(b => b.BookId == long.Parse(id));
//apply all filters
foreach (var f in filters)
    query = query.Where(f);
```

Your questions:

1. This question requires an example of input and output. Try something like this:

   `|| pstmt.vcr_MetaKey=="Publish Date" && (
    pstmt.vcr_MetaValue == "" || DateTime.Parse(pstmt.vcr_MetaValue) < DateTime.Now)`
2. There is method AsEnumerable, if you mean what I think.

Comment: you are close ,i am assuming that query will have a concatenated result based on all f?

Comment: ok secondly can i make a field independent variable filters as in my case bookId would be row not a column? that's the real problem

Comment: I don't think that there is any "not column filters" except Skip and Take combination (they are filters by row number). Field independent filters can be achieved using string queries, for example in Entity Framework: dc.SomeTable.Where("it.["+columnName+"] = '"+columnValue+"'");

Comment: If you want to concatenate filters as "OR", not as "AND", you can read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569671/c-linq2sql-is-it-possible-to-concatenate-two-queryables-into-one. Here is link about dynamic queries with Linq2Sql: http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/314663.aspx